# Django Rest - Use @action with custom decorator

Tags: django, rest

I have a Rest API in Django and I have the following method in a class that extends ModelViewSet:

```py
@custom_decorator
@action(methods=['get'], detail=False, url_name="byname", url_path="byname")
def get_by_name(self, request):
    # get query params from get request
    username = request.query_params["username"]
    experiment = request.query_params["experiment"]
```

If I remove the first annotator everything works fine. But when I am trying to call this function with both decorators, it does not even find the specific url path.

Is it possible to use multiple decorators along with the @action decorator?

Comment: What if you use `custom_decorator` decorator as second?

Comment: I tried that too. In general, when I keep this decorator, API calls fail

Comment: Can you add the error traceback?

Comment: {
    "detail": "Not found."
}

Comment: What happens inside the custom decorator? Add the code

Comment: For now it's not yet implemented. Just checks a param in the request if exists and continues with the function if yes otherwise it returns 500 error. The weird thing is that when I override the list function and add the decorator, it works fine. But in a custom function with the @action it does not work, and I get the above response

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution, unfortunately. I implemented a different workaround by overriding a Django permission class (the decorator was related to user permissions)

Comment: @TFischer check Adolfo's answer below. I tried it and worked fine!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was having the same issue and fixed it the following way:

```
from functools import wraps

def custom_decorator(func):
  # ADD THIS LINE TO YOUR CUSTOM DECORATOR
  @wraps(func)
  def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  return func_wrapper

@action(methods=['get'], detail=False, url_name="byname", url_path="byname")
@custom_decorator
def get_by_name(self, request):
  # other code
```

I believe the issue is that the action decorator does not recognize the function after adding `custom_decorator` because the name is changed, so by adding `@wraps(func)` the function name stays the same. ([@wraps docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps))